# WebScrap Error from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm learning how to web scrap with python but when I try it it's getting me an error

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("website.html") as file:
    contents = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
print(soup.title)
```

Image - https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/909674358690156594/955073329226739732/unknown.png?width=1250&height=671

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried previously checking if bs4 is installed?

Running `!pip list` will yield a list of all installed modules. If bs4 is not there, then you can run:

```
!pip install bs4
```

And then try importing it again.